# on text click show image name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show image name on text click without creating multiple id for text click. In this piece of code I have done this on image click but I want it on text click.If it can be done through class name or single id then do it because I have 100 of images I don't want to write same code for multiple files.

```js
$('img').click(function()
{
 var test = $(this).attr('src').split("/").pop();
 document.getElementById("result").value= test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div>
     <img src="1.png">
     <p>click<p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="2.png">
     <p>click</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="3.png">
     <p>click</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't just ask us to 'do it'

Comment: Set you click event on `p` and change `$(this)` to `$(this).prev('img')`.

Comment: hello suraj S  i am not asking u to do it. Rather  am  just asking for help, if any could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Do it like below:-***

```js
$('p').click(function(){//on click of paragraph
 var test = $(this).prev('img').attr('src').split("/").pop(); // get the current click paragraph parent div image src and find out the name of image by using split
 $("#result").val(test); // update the name in text-field
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div>
     <img src="1.png">
     <p>click<p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="2.png">
     <p>click</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="3.png">
     <p>click</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

***Note:-*** don't mix `javascript and jQuery` with each-other. Use either-one purely.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('p').click(function()
{
    var test = $(this).parent('div').find('img').attr('src').split("/").pop();
    document.getElementById("result").value= test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <img src="1.png">
        <p>click<p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="2.png">
        <p>click</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="3.png">
        <p>click</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find `img` tag and apply class to `p` tag in our case `.clickelem` please find below snippet for more info.

```js
$('.clickelem').click(function()
{
  var test = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src').split("/").pop();
  document.getElementById("result").value= test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div>
     <img src="1.png" />
     <p class="clickelem">click<p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="2.png" />
     <p class="clickelem">click</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="3.png" />
     <p class="clickelem">click</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //option one set onclick on every p tag
    $('img').parent().find('p').click(function() {
        var test = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src').split("/").pop();
        document.getElementById("result").value= test;
    });

    //option two set onclick on parent div and filter events
    $('.row').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
            return;
        }
        var test = $(e.target).parent().find('img').attr('src').split("/").pop();
        document.getElementById("result").value= test;
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div>
      <img src="1.png">
      <p class='para'>click<p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="2.png">
     <p class='para'>click</p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="3.png">
     <p class='para'>click</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('.para').click(function()
{
    var imageSrc = $(this).prev("img");
    var test = $(this).attr('src').split("/").pop();
    document.getElementById("result").value= test;
});
```